# MongoDB textScore by word position

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, aggregate

How can I set text search in MongoDB to give a higher score to results where the keywords appear first?

For instance, here's what I'm doing right now:

```
db.product.aggregate(
  [
    { $match: { $text: { $search: "notebook acer" }, isAvailable: true } },
    { $sort: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } },
    { $project: { searchName: 1, _id: 0, score: { $meta: "textScore" } } }
  ]
)
```

And in the results I get:

```
{
    "searchName" : "Mochila para Notebook Acer",
    "score" : 1.25
},
{
    "searchName" : "Notebook Acer E5-471-36me Intel Core I3 1.90ghz 4gb Hdd 500gb Linux Hdmi",
    "score" : 1.0625
}
```

But I need the second result to come first, because the keywords appear first in the indexed field.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to use the operator **$indexOfCP**, you can calculate the position of your word with that one, and after you can sort on this position you calculated.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfCP/

For the position part it's something like this:

```
db.product.aggregate(
   [
     { $project: { kwPosition: { $indexOfCP: [ "$searchName", "notebook acer" ] } } },
     { $match: { "kwPosition": {"$ne": -1} } },
     { $sort: { kwPosition: 1 } }
   ]
)
```

You can combine both logics.

Comment: Do you know how I could create an average value for both scores?
 Something like `(textScore + kwPosition)/2`

Comment: Also, is it possible get the indexOfCP for each word separately?

Comment: You can combine values with project, nobody stops you from adding another project stage where you mix your values as you need.
About the second one, I guess you have to split your search string in more tokens before, using $indexOfCP for each one in the project stage.